# Inject Custom Implementation for Identity UserStore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simple-injector

I have added custom implementation of UserStore. For the user store constructor I inject UserRepository how can I register that with simple injector container

my code like

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<User>, IUserLoginStore<User>, IUserPasswordStore<User>,
    IUserSecurityStampStore<User>, IUserEmailStore<User>
{
    private readonly IRepository<User> _userRepository;

    public UserStore(IRepository<User> userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    //other implementations
}
```

my UserManager Class

```
public  class UserStoreManager<T> : UserManager<User> where T : class 
{ 
    public UserStoreManager(IUserStore<User> store) : base(store)
    {

    }
}
```

**Update**

i have tried this by registering like this

```
container.Register<IUserStore<User>, UserStore>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<UserManager<User>, UserStoreManager<User>>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

then i got an exception

[image]

Comment: i have no idea how to register IUserStore to container i tried with this `container.Register<IUserStore<User>>(() => new UserStore(), Lifestyle.Scoped);` but need default constructor initialized with IRepository<User> type

Comment: Can you not register type with the simple-injector, instead of adding an initializer (and if you have to add the lambda for initializing, can you not do container.Resolve<IRepository<User>>() to use it as a parameter?

Comment: @Icepickle i'm not sure i understood you correctly could you please add some code sample ?

Comment: Have you tried understanding what the reported warnings mean and why Simple Injector reported them to you? You can find a detailed description about those warnings, why they are problematic and how to fix them here: https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to initialize `UserStore` I just use the following

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUserStore<User>>(() => new UserStore<User>((IRepository<User>)container.GetInstance<IRepository<User>>()));
```

`UserStore` needs the an instance of the context, however it is only possible to get the current context with `GetInstance` since it is "calculated on runtime", depending on the Context lifestyle

**Edit 1**

For `UserManager` you need to do the following:

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest(() => new ApplicationUserManager(container.GetInstance<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(), DataProtectionProvider));
```

It follows the same principle as the above.

`DataProtectionProvider` is an argument of my method called `InitializeContainer`

```
private static void InitializeContainer(Container container, IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider)
{
    /* OMITTED */
    container.RegisterPerWebRequest(() => new ApplicationUserManager(container.GetInstance<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(), DataProtectionProvider));
}
```

which is used on:

```
public static void InitializeInjector(this IAppBuilder app, IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider)
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
    container.Options.PropertySelectionBehavior = new PropertySelectionBehavior<InjectAttribute>();

    InitializeContainer(container, DataProtectionProvider); // Here
    app.UseOwinContextInjector(container);
    app.MapSignalR(container);

    container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    container.Verify();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));

    BinderConfig.RegisterModelBinders(container);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters, container);
}
```

which is called on

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
    app.InitializeInjector(app.GetDataProtectionProvider());
}
```

So, `DataProtectionProvider` comes from the `IAppBuilder`